# 301 redirect from /public_html to /newdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

My client had his website in `/public_html` (PHP). I was building him a new website (PHP). The week we were prepping to launch he was hacked. His web person moved the new website from `/public_html/sub` to `/sub` and pointed the domain at it.

My client has lost his Google ranking. I don't have access to the cPanel. Do I need to do a 301 redirect to try to get his ranking back? Any other suggestions?

Comment: How as the external URL (what google sees) change?

Comment: The external URL is the same. It hasn't changed.

Comment: Then how does the ranking change if google can't tell that anything has changed?

Comment: I have no clue and am totally stumped by this.

Comment: I think I figured it out. When the site was hacked the web person blocked a bunch of IPs and such. I believe this includes Google. ACK! Now, can anyone can tell me how to get the ranking back?!